# Jquery - Loop Through An Array DIVs, show and hide them

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery/Javascript.  Is there a good way to put bunch of elements in an array and loop through it, call a function to do something.  Lets me explain what I am trying to do.

I have this code below will hide and show the 2 DIVs when the mouse click outside of the DIV.  It works great. However, I have alot of DIVs to show and hide.  Please show me a way to put in a array of DIVs, convert below code to the function ShowHideDIV(hideDiv, showDiv) to perform the action?

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var showContainer1 = $("#divShipMethod");
    var hideContainer1 = $("#divShipMethodDDL");

    if (!hideContainer1.is(e.target) 
        && hideContainer1.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        hideContainer1.hide();
        showContainer1.show();
    }
});
```

For example, Says I have the following DIV IDs like to put in an array:

1. divShow1
2. divHide1
3. divShow2
4. divHide2
5. divShow3
6. divHide3
7. divShow4
8. divHide4
9. divShow5
10. divHide5

Comment: You can use `$.each()` to loop through an array with jQuery.

Comment: You likely don't need to loop at all, a common classname among the differing types of divs would probably be easier to maintain.

Comment: how can I put those DIVs in an array and loop through it? I am new to Jquery, code example would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Just like Kevin indicated, the "jQuery way" is to use classes and ids appropriately and refer to the items in that way.  So if you want to deal with all of those divs together, they should be in a class (by adding `class="foo"` to the divs) and then you refer to them all with `$('.foo')`.  Then you could loop them like `$('.foo').each(function () { /* do something */ };` or perhaps hide them all with `$('.foo').hide();` with no loop at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using IDs for your divs, give them a class name (all the same)

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var showContainer1 = $(".divShipMethod");   
    var hideContainer1 = $(".divShipMethodDDL");

    if (!hideContainer1.is(e.target) 
        && hideContainer1.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        hideContainer1.hide();
        showContainer1.show();
    }
});
```